# printf string output "Ç²↕" getch() C++

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, printf

I want the output to say what arrow key the user pressed.
The output I get is:

```
"You pressed the Ç²↕ button."
```

What I wrote was:

```
unsigned int key;
string K;
do
{
    key = getch();
    if (key==72)
        K=" up";
    else if(key==80)
        K="down";
    else if (key==77)
        K="right";
    else if (key==75)
        K="left";
    else
        {}
    if (key!=224)
        printf("You pressed the %s button.\n", K);
    else
        {}
}while(key !='q');

return;
```

Comment: The compiler should complain here...

Comment: What is `getch()` returning? Almost certainly, you're printing an uninitialized string with garbage in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

should do `std::cout << "You have pressed " << K << " button." << std::endl;`  You have mixed `string` object type with `printf`.   `printf` only accepts a `char *` or `char []` with the `%s` format string.

Or you might want to access the c string associated with the `string` object with `K.c_str ()`

`printf ("\ntest %s", K.c_str ());`

Comment: thanks for pointing out, i am a c programmer so it is a habit.

Comment: In general, the C++ Standard Library is preferable to C runtime (CRT). There's a way to do all the things you are used to, usually (but not always) elegant. For advanced usage and to amaze and impress your friends, check out http://www.boost.org :-)

Comment: @Steve Townsend: You should only use `std::endl` if you want output to be flushed. :)

Comment: @greyfade - did not know that, thanks.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n

Answer (score 4):

`printf` is not type-safe, if you pass it mismatched input it is prone to misbehave randomly.  Try

```
printf("You pressed the %s button.\n", K.c_str());
```

Better still, in C++ use `operator<<` as noted in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

You print out K, but in case it was not one of the arrows pressed, you don't initialize K. Assign K=key before the if statements.

Comment: for `string();` Content is initialized to an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

printf needs a char* not a std::string try with

```
printf("You pressed the %s button.\n", K.c_str());
```